# Issue with user creation in linux

Tags: linux

I want to create two user with only read permission to their home folder.
And other new user which can read write and execute the file in above two user folders.

Answer (score 0):

This is not (easily) possible with linux as some files are written to the home directory (e.g. `.xsession-errors` or `.bash_history`).

You can create a new group and assign this group to the users that only read files. Then give the file permission `rw-r-----` to the files and assign the created greoup to the files. So the users can only read the files. Also you can give the permission `rwxr-x---` and assign the group to all directories so that the users may not write files into directories.

Comment: I have to create user for sftp login.

Comment: @KalimSayyed and why should this users not be able to write? Should they only download files?

Comment: yes..they only download files

Comment: @KalimSayyed I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KalimSayyed: Doesn't SFTP allow setting of different "home" directories where the user ends up on login? That would allow to set them to a read-only directory (for them).